# Como buscar por palavras em um JSON usando Ionic?

Tags: php, javascript, angularjs, ionic

Tenho um JSON e ele é paginado. Quando ele não era paginado, quando digitava qualquer coisa na busca, ele buscava o que era impresso na tela, como no exemplo a seguir:

```
<form ng-submit="fechaTeclado()">
            <div class="bar bar-subheader bar-light">
                <label class="item item-input item-floating-label">
                    <i class="icon ion-search placeholder-icon"></i>
                    <input type="text" size="100" ng-model="q" placeholder="Procurar" type="submit" ng-submit="fechaTeclado()" ng-click="fechaTeclado()" />
                    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="OK" ng-click="fechaTeclado()" />

                </label>
            </div>
        </form>

  <div class="card" ng-repeat="item in ofertass | filter:q | orderBy:someModel | unique: 'cadastra_oferta_cod_oferta'" ng-init="$last ? fireEvent() : null" href="#/nhaac/ofertas_singles/{{item.cadastra_oferta_cod_oferta}}">
```

Agora que paginei, ele continua buscando somente o que está impresso, já carregado na paginação.

Como posso realizar uma busca pelo meu JSON sem a necessidade de carregar todos os registros na tela?

Segue o trecho de meu controller com a paginação:

```
$scope.pagination = {
        limit: 8,
        offset: 0
    };
    $scope.pagination.limit = 8;
    $scope.pagination.offset = 0;
    $scope.noMoreItemsAvailable = false;
    $scope.ofertass = [];
    $scope.getRecord = function () {
        $http.get("http://meusite.com.br/admin/apis/api_listagem/lista_oferta_api.php?json=promocao" + "&latitude=" + $scope.lat_cliente + "&longitude=" + $scope.long_cliente + "&raio=" + $scope.raio + "&limit=" + $scope.pagination.limit + "&offset=" + $scope.pagination.offset).then(function (response) {
                // console.log(response.data);
                if (response.data.length) {
                    $scope.ofertass.push.apply($scope.ofertass, response.data);
                    $scope.pagination.offset = $scope.pagination.offset + $scope.pagination.limit;
                    window.localStorage.setItem("data_ofertass", JSON.stringify(response.data));

                } else {
                    $scope.noMoreItemsAvailable = true;
                    if (window.localStorage.getItem("data_ofertass") === null) {
                        $state.go("nhaac.nachegamos");
                    }

                }
            },
            function (response) {
                // error message
                var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
                    title: "error " + response.status,
                    template: response.statusText + "<br/>Problema: Conexão com sua Internet.",
                });
            }).finally(function () {
            console.log("finally....");
            $scope.$broadcast('scroll.infiniteScrollComplete');

        });
    }

    $scope.doRefresh = function () {
        limit = 20;
        offset = 0;
        $scope.noMoreItemsAvailable = false;
        $scope.getRecord();
    };



    if (data_ofertass === null) {
        data_ofertass = [];



        window.localStorage.getItem("endereco_temp");
        window.localStorage.getItem("endereco_atual");
    };
```

Comment: Cara, não sei se vc já resolveu, eu cheguei a comentar lá no face, mas apaguei pq não conheço angular/ionic tão profundamente para saber se tem alguma mágica... se não tem mágica, a solução padrão é vc passar o dado da busca para o seu backend para que ele já gere o json filtrado para vc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi utilizando POG!

Segue a resolução:

```
$scope.fechaTeclado = function () {
        $cordovaKeyboard.close();

        if ($scope.q === '') {
            $scope.q = '';
            window.localStorage.setItem("q", $scope.q);
            $scope.pagination = {
                limit: 10,
                offset: 0
            };
            $scope.pagination.limit = 8;
            $scope.pagination.offset = 0;
            $scope.noMoreItemsAvailable = false;
            $scope.ofertass = [];

            $scope.getRecord();

        } else {



            window.localStorage.setItem("q", $scope.q);

         //   $scope.q = window.localStorage.getItem("q");

            $scope.pagination = {
                limit: 10,
                offset: 0
            };
            $scope.pagination.limit = 8;
            $scope.pagination.offset = 0;
            $scope.noMoreItemsAvailable = false;
            $scope.ofertass = [];

            $scope.getRecord();
        }
    };
```